# Allow undefined variables to pass into Firebase as null

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Is there a way to allow variables which are undefined to pass into Firebase as null?  In my application I have a lot of cases where a variable might not be defined and it prevents the entire object model from being added into firebase.  So I have to detect if each potential variable is defined and then set it to 0 if it isn't.  It would be a lot easier if Firebase just accepted undefined variables as 0 or null.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the logical OR operator to pass `null` if the initial value is falsy.

```
ref.set(someValue || null);
```

What you'll have to remember is that there are a lot of conditions that will result in `null` here (`0`, `false`, `''`, `undefined`, `NaN` etc).

Alternatively, you could write a helper function which wrapped this behaviour up with a cleaner check.

```
function safeSet(ref, val) {
  if(val == undefined) {
    ref.set(null);
  } else {
    ref.set(val);
  }
}
```

You could probably even patch the function into the Firebase Reference prototype if you wanted.

```
Firebase.prototype.safeSet = function safeSet(val) {
  if(typeof val == 'undefined') {
    this.set(null);
  } else {
    this.set(val);
  }
};
```

Which would allow you to call the `safeSet` method directly on your existing Firebase references.

```
var ref = new Firebase("myapp.firebaseio.com");
var val = [1, 2, 3][-1];
ref.safeSet(val);
```

Comment: I'm passing in an entire object to the set, and some of the elements of the object are undefined, is there a way to detect for that?

Comment: Not without first traversing the object. You could take the same principles as shown here and use them to create a `safeObject` function, which nulled all undefined properties.